# Rails publify error when running rake db:migrate db:seed on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, carrierwave, publify

I'm getting this error when I run rake db:migrate db:seed on heroku for my rails publify blog

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/fog-core-1.27.3/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in `validate_options'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/fog-core-1.27.3/lib/fog/core/service.rb:268:in `handle_settings'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/fog-core-1.27.3/lib/fog/core/service.rb:98:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/fog-core-1.27.3/lib/fog/storage.rb:25:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:83:in `eager_load_fog'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:96:in `fog_credentials='
/app/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:118:in `configure'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
/app/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application.rb:405:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
```

I've already set these arguments in the terminal for AWS according to the instructions on publify's github page - https://github.com/publify/publify

What am i missing?

Comment: How did you set your `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` arguments locally? You mentioned you set them in the terminal. Did you set them as environment variables?

Comment: heroku config:set provider=AWS
aws_access_key_id= "my access key id"
aws_secret_access_key= "my secret access key"
aws_bucket= "bucket name"

Comment: Can you confirm they are set? Run `heroku config` and see if the variables are set.

Comment: here's what my carrierwave initializer looks like https://github.com/nerboda/myblog/blob/master/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

Comment: what would i get if they are set? i ran it and it doesnt say anything about the access key id or secret access key

Comment: It should list the key-value pairs for your app's environment variables. Run these commands to add the AWS credentials: `heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=PasteTheKeyInHereNoQuotes` and `heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=PasteTheSecretKeyHereAlsoNoQuotes`. Then to confirm these are set, run `heroku config` and you should see both listed. Lastly, run `heroku run console` in the Terminal and type `ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']` and you should see the value of the key you added in the previous step. Then, re-run your migrations.

Comment: alright so prefixing each command with heroku config:set was what i was missing. that did the trick. thanks so much for the help

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. I'll add an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run these commands to add the AWS credentials: `heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=PasteTheKeyInHereNoQuotes` and `heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=PasteTheSecretKeyHereAlsoNoQuotes`. Then, to confirm these are set, run `heroku config` and you should see both listed. Lastly, run `heroku run console` in the Terminal and type `ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']` and you should see the value of the key you added in the previous step. Then, re-run your migrations.